# I want query count record of colum according to another two colums

Tags: mysql

I have this table called systemtrack this table record track of user in system :

examble of my table :

```
user_id , event_id
 1      ,   1
 1      ,   1
 1      ,   2
 2      ,   2
 1      ,   3
```

I want query Calculated number of visit of every event but if user visit event more than one time ,  count only one visit

I want this result

```
 event_id  , CountofVisitEvent
 1         ,   1
 2         ,   2
 3         ,   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`

```
SELECT  event_id, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS CountofVisitEvent
FROM systemtrack
GROUP BY  event_id
```